# Request does not return complete response. Error JSON.parse

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, request

I have a problem in nodejs, I make a request to an api using `https.request`, the response contains an object of 10000 rows.
What happens is that the entire object does not arrive, and parsing gives the error: `Unexpected end of JSON input`;

Can someone help?

Function to request:

```
function request({
  options,
  method,
  resource,
  queryParams,
  bodyParams,
}) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const hasBodyParams = !!bodyParams;

    const stringifyedQueryParams = strigifyQueryParams(queryParams);

    const optionsRequest = {
      ...options,
      method,
      path: `${resource}${stringifyedQueryParams}`,
    };

    const req = https.request(optionsRequest, (res) => {
      res.setEncoding(configs.ENCODING);
      res.on(events.DATA, data => resolve({
        body: JSON.parse(data),
        statusCode: res.statusCode,
      }));
    });

    req.on(events.ERROR, error => reject(error) );
    hasBodyParams && req.write(bodyParams);
    req.end();
  });
}
```

Comment: In order to help we need to see your code and the JSON source.

Comment: Please post your JSON data, and your parsing code

Comment: The request is a simple request. In `postman` i recive complet json. I using sampe request: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/https.html. recive incomplet json data in event res.on('data'.

Comment: @CláudioHilário post your Nodejs code so we can be sure. The `data`-event might be called multiple times! So you have to combine everything and parse the complete string.

Comment: I've updated the question can assume that is, in the event date should receive the full json.

Comment: As per the documentation, when using `https.request`, you'll get several `request.on( 'data', ... )` calls before the `request.on ('end' )` is triggered when requesting large data sets. As you show in your code, instead of waiting for the 'end' event , then concatenate the chunks and respond with the full JSON, you respond with a partial JSON on the first chunk. Use `.get()` if you do not want to deal with merging the chunks again or fix the code to use the 'end' event.

Comment: Thanks Shilly. My problem is solved :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I suspected in the comments, you're not handling multiple `data`-events.

- When receiving large responses from a request, the `data`-event is called multiple times, each time with a chunk of data from the response (**not** the complete response).
- When you're parsing a chunk, the complete JSON document hasn't been transmitted yet, so the parsing fails with the "Unexpected end of JSON stream" error

In short, you need to:

1. Create a variable to collect the complete body
2. On a `data`-event, append the new chunk to the complete body
3. When the `end`-event is called, parse the full body.

Here is a short example, adopted from the [official documentation](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v9.x/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback):

```
https.request(options, (res) => {
  // PARTIAL example
  res.setEncoding("utf8"); // makes sure that "chunk" is a string.
  let fullBody = "";

  res.on("data", data => {
    fullBody += data;
  });
  res.on("end", () => {
    const json = JSON.parse(fullBody);
    // work with json
  });
});
```